# deploying as webapp with multiple doGet() present

Tags: google-apps-script

I started learning/working with Google App Scripts recently and learnt that the file in Google Drive is really a "project" inside which I could add multiple "scripts" or "HTML files". And "Deploy as webapp" seems to deploy the project and not an individual script.

As such I can have a `doGet(e)` method implemented in more than one scripts. I just tried it and it started picking up the `doGet(e)` method I added in a second script that I added more recently.

Could someone clarify what is the expectation when multiple `doGet(e)` and/or `doPost(e)` implementations are present? I don't see a mention of this scenario in the docs and it has left me kind of confused.

Comment: You can serve multiple pages with one doGet() by using querystrings added to the WebApp url.  Checkout e.parameter and e.parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Answer (score 2):

A Google Apps Script project should use unique names for each function. That means that we should not have several function called doGet(e) on the same project otherwise the last function to be loaded will be the one that will served when it's name is called.

Related

- [Function Scope Rules (Google Apps Script Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19759985/1595451)